# How to export events from misp to a csv file using api

Tags: api, security, malware

I am new to the misp platform and I need a dataset that I can feed to a neural network for malware detection, the problem is I don't know how to export the events from my misp instance to a csv file using the api (because in the interface exports I can't find misp_context in the downloaded csv file)? can anyone help, thanks already.